# Calling one method from another method that does not take input as part of its signature (Java)

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I have this method that returns deposit amount

```
public double take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account() throws InputMismatchException {
    System.out.println("Enter the amount to be depsosited in the format XX:YY");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double deposit_amount = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("You have deposited " + deposit_amount + " into your checkings account ");
    user_option(); // call user option
    return deposit_amount;

}
```

I have a secound method (see below) that does not take input as part of its signature but will leverage the return value from the take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account() above.

after  doing the initialization beleow,

double deposit_amount = take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account();

```
public double withdrawl_from_checking() throws InputMismatchException {
    System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to deposit");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double withdrawl_amount = sc.nextDouble();
    double depositAmount = deposit_amount;
    double balance_after_withdrawal = 0;
    if (withdrawl_amount > 0.0 && withdrawl_amount >= depositAmount) {
        balance_after_withdrawal = depositAmount - withdrawl_amount;
        System.out.println(" You have made a withdrawal in the amount of " + withdrawl_amount
                + " You balance is now " + balance_after_withdrawal);

    } else if (withdrawl_amount > depositAmount) {
        System.out.println(" Insifficient funds: withdrwal amount is greater than current balance");

    }
    return balance_after_withdrawal;

}
```

I STILL CANNOT SUCCESSFULLY pass the actual value of deposit_amount into the double withdrawl_from_checking()

I do not know how else to use the return value from my first method in the second one.

Comment: where did u call take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account method from withdrawl_from_checking method ?

Comment: HINT: `take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account()` didn't really _take_ any amount _into_ any account: it just  solicited an input amount from the user and returned it. Where did the money go after that?  Where's the "checking account" from which `withdrawl_from_checking()` is supposedly withdrawing?

Comment: thanks for the note, I stored the user input double deposit_amount = sc.nextDouble(); the into a variable (double deposit_amount_from_user), then used that variable in my logic, the variable still behaved exact the way the method behaved   // take deposit $ from user
 public double take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account() throws...
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  double deposit_amount = sc.nextDouble();
  double deposit_amount_from_user = deposit_amount;

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get the exactly what are you trying to do but below are my initial findings

take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account should be called somewhere from 
withdrawl_from_checking should method . so you should change the

```
double depositAmount = deposit_amount;
```

to

```
double depositAmount = take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account();
```

Comment: initilaizing double depositAmount = take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account(); inside withdrawl_from_checking() does not assign the return value deposit_amount as I wanted. Instead, it is acting as calling the take_deposit_amount_into_checking_account(). that is, it is prompting for " amoun to deposit" instead of assigning the value of deposit_amount to double depositAmount.